# Strange Exception with cloud storage

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I'm using google cloud storage and sometimes, it returns exception with message "1".
I checked written file and it was missing some parts.

Can somebody tell me what is that exception ? Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you add a bit more specific info (like the exact exception you are seeing)? Additionally, the following topic on SO (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10672457/io-exception-when-writing-files-to-google-cloud-storage) indicates that parts of Google Cloud Storage are still experimental; so you might be suffering from a problem related to that...

Answer (score 0):

If you could, please capture request and response headers and send them to us at gs-team (-at-) google.com if you see this happen again, and we'll take a look.

Thanks,
Navneet